# Add a timer for every row added to dataGridView and remove it if row deleted

Tags: c#, datagridview, timer

I'm trying to add a timer for every row added to dataGridView and remove it if a row is deleted.

I cannot get the timer to run at all because of errors:

'System.Timers.Timer' does not contain a definition for 'Tick' and no extension method 'Tick' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Timers.Timer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The name 'myTimer_Tick' does not exist in the current context

This is an example of what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Media;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;

private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    myTimer.Interval = 30000;
    myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
    myTimer.Start();
}

public void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("30 seconds scince you added a row");
}

private void dataGridView1_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
{
    //remove a timer here that corresponds to this row, 
    //if row removed before timer elapsed
}
```

Thankyou for any help I may receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `System.Timer` has no `.Tick` event. Use `Timer.Elapsed` instead:

```
myTimer.Elapsed += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
```

[EDIT: Replaced List with Dictionary]

You also need multiple timers and a way to keep the timer in scope. Using a `Dictiory<DataGridViewRow, Timer>` object declared at the class level:

```
private Dictionary<DataGridViewRow, System.Timers.Timer> timers = new Dictionary<DataGridViewRow, System.Timers.Timer>();

private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    var myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    myTimer.Interval = 30000;
    myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
    myTimer.Enabled = true;

    // Potential bug source: If you programmatically add multiple rows at once,
    // a timer is only added to the first row
    timers.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex], myTimer);
}
```

Now in the RowsRemoved event handler, you get the row index and remove it from the `timers` dictionary; eg, `timers.RemoveAt(rowIndex)`.

Comment: That still trows me an error on the EventHandler line. I can supress it by using myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MyTimer_Tick); would that be right?

Comment: If somehow `Rows` collection gets reordered, your row collection indices will not match up with `timers` indices. A Row reference as a key to a `Dictionary<DataRow, Timer>` collection will be less likely to cause collisions due to mismatched indices.

Comment: That's true I didn't think of that. The user is allowed to re-arrange the rows, but not the colums. How would I add it using Dictionary<DataRow, Timer>?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer
```

Instead of

```
using System.Timers;
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) vs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

Comment: OK I have changed it to that, thanks. They both produce the same result. I cannot remove the timer with either of them though and the timer keeps repeating. How do I stop this?